# How do I use a list on one tab in Excel to create new columns in another tab?

Tags: excel, vba, customization

I would need some help with creating a customizable table in MS Excel.

I am trying to put together a MS Excel spreadsheet for work to track certain metrics in our day to day operation. I would like the file to be rather flexible in the combination of metrics that it will allow to be tracked when finished.

I have one tab in the spreadsheet that contains the various metrics that I would like to track information for, and I would like to be able to simply go into that tab, mark the relevant entries by entering an "x" in the cell next to them, and have a column added in the main tab of the file for every entry marked this way. Any values for these entries will entered manually in the main tab, in the rows for the appropriate sub sets, which are permanent cell values in the main tab. I would just like to be able to create a custom table in one tab, with appropriate columns based on the desired/marked data in the second tab. I know that this will require programming some macros, but I don't know how to create a macro that will allow me to click a button in the spreadsheet and then have the spreadsheet automatically add columns for each value selected in the secondary tab.

How can I program a macro, that enables a button to be pressed in the spreadsheet, which will then look up any cells marked with an "x" next to them and create a new column in tab1 using the value of each cell in tab2 as the header in the table in tab1? I can't find any information online on what coding commands would perform that task and since there is no way in Excel to complete this other than looking up the header info and writing it into the relevant cells myself, I can't find any associations to help me figure this out myself either.

Comment: Which exact part is giving you a problem? Think about how you'd do it manually, then recreate the logic in VBA - if there's a specific part of that you're not sure about, then it would help to explain it in your post.  "how can I create a macro that will ..." is a bit too broad. [ask]

Comment: @TimWilliams, I thought it was clear from the post that the code is giving me the problem. I don't know how to program macros. I would need some help with the entire code, top to bottom, since I can't find anywhere to get that information without signing up for full advanced Excel class that would probably take me three months to get anywhere near the info I need and I was hoping to be able to have this figured out by the end of this week. There is no other way to do this than a macro, since the only other option is to hand write the table myself every time I need to change the set up.

Comment: @ForcePushThinkr, SO platform doesn't encourage such broad questions. Let's us say even if someone gave you the code, how will you go about implementing it in your excel. e.g. do you know how to create a macro, do you know how to create a button, do you know how to link a macro to a button. If you do, great, you have already done some groundwork, if not try to pick those up first, and then explain what you have completed and where are you headed to on your next step. I'm trying to see if I can provide you a code sample to get you started on these lines

Answer (score 0):

Here is the macro code.

Excel Setup:

1. Your list of values should be present in "Sheet2", Columns A & B
2. There is a limit of 20 values, modify the code if you have more values in your list
3. Values will be copied over to "Sheet1" Row1 start Column B onwards

> ```
> Sub CreateTable()
> '
> ' CreateTable Macro
> '
>
> '
> Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, cell As Range
> Dim i As Integer, destCol As Integer, limit As Integer
>
> destCol = 2
> limit = 20
>
> 'Clear values from the Column headers that already exist from previous run
> For i = 2 To limit + 2
>     Cells(1, i) = ""
> Next i
>
> 'Write new column headers based upon the updated list
> For i = 1 To limit
>     If Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i) = "x" Then
>         Cells(1, destCol).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i)
>         destCol = destCol + 1
>     End If
> Next i
>
> End Sub
> ```